# I am getting a strange error when trying to install mysqlclient on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, ubuntu-18.04, libmysql

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev libmysqlclient-dev -y
```

Output:

```
After this operation, 10.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 zlib1g-dev amd64 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2                                                                    
  Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (103.97.84.254), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib1g-dev_1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f), connection timed out Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (103.97.84.254), connection timed out
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Does someone know to workaround this issue

Answer (score 2):

It seems like apt could not connect to the right archive. Maybe there's an option, where you can change the server to download from.
Also you could try running `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev libmysqlclient-de --fix-missing` as suggested in the error message.

**Edit:**
I found out, that you can change the mirror by going to `software sources` (Linux Mint, maybe this also works for you)

Comment: It shows E: Unable to locate package libmysqlclient-de
So how should I install the missing package as its a important dependency for my software.

Comment: Do `sudo apt install libmysqlclient-de --fix-missing`

Comment: Yes I did ,It shows Unable to locate package libmysqlclient-de

Comment: Oh, ok. Did you try changing the mirror for your apt downloads? What OS do you use?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04